# iOS 4.2 SDK download

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

Does anyone know where I can get the iOS 4.2 SDK for xCode?  I cannot find it anywhere on the Apple site.

I am building an App for Verizon Phones which only supports iOS 4.2.  I get a runtime error that says 'Symbol not found' for AdInterstitialAd.  I am not sure, but I am guessing I am getting that error because I added the iAd.framework from the iOS 4.3 SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit an app to the App Store you will always build against the latest SDK which is 4.3. Apple will reject your app if you don't. You can set the deployment version of your app to lower version. And you are correct, `AdInterstitialAd` is only available in 4.3 or higher. You can still use the `ADBannerView` in the lower version.

If you want to use `AdInterstitialAd` in your app, you will have to use weak linking to make sure the framework if avaiable.

For example:

```
class adClass = NSClassFromString(@"AdInterstitialAd");
If (adClass) {
    // do full screen ad stuff
} else if ((adClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView")) {
    // do banner ad stuff
}
```

[Using iAds While Maintaining Backwards Compatibility](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/68) is a blog that provide some tips for using iAds when it was first announced last year. Some of those tips are this valuable today.

Comment: Sorry I miss typed.  I do not need the firmware.  I need the iOS 4.2 SDK Framework.

Comment: The advice here is correct -- you don't need the 4.2 SDK, you need the latest SDK. Just set the deployment target in your project's build settings to iOS 4.2.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that, but when I choose to build for the iPad 4.3 asClass is null. So I don't get it, I have a universal project and I need to build iPhone for 4.2 and later, iPad I want to use AdInterstitialAd to show a full screen ad. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Figured out what I was doing wrong... misspelled the class name!!  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: That is one of the downfall of weak linking.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/