# How to get ios4.3 SDKs in Xcode 4.1 for lion osx?

Tags: ios

Ha ii,everybody,i just want to know about how to get or download ios-4.3  in Xcode 4.1 for lion osx?.I bought a new mac mini which have Lion os x.So i can't install my xcode-4 in lion osx,am doing my projects in 4.3 so if i download the Xcode 4.1 or later for lion os am not able to build my application in it.so is there any download link for downloading Xcode 4.1 or later with iOS 4.3 or below?.How to solve this issue?please help me.I know this is not a code related question,but i need this information that i want urgently thus why am asking this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: xcode 4.3 should have rollback capability. Have you tried cleaning the project and then compiling? Make sure you have the right build phase selecting in the properties. Also if you have a device with 4.3 on it, you can plug it in, and organizer will pick it up as an unidentified device and copy the relevant iosx build info across.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 4.2 SDK download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668287/ios-4-2-sdk-download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to your projects build settings -> Summary and set the "Deployment Target" to "4.3".

Comment: but the app store decryption how only ion in Xcode 4.1 for lion.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You will only get the latest SDK from Apple. But there is a difference between **SDK** and **Deployment Target**. So you have the 5.0 SDK but will **deploy to 4.3**, which in turn means you won't have the 5.0 features even though using the 5.0 SDK but rather you have what you had when 4.3 was the current SDK. Your app will run perfectly well on 4.3.

Comment: so i cn build my 4.3 application in Xcode 4.2 for lion right?so i can download with no tension right?hheee

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

In xcode 4.2 for snow leopard is an ability to choose "More simulators..." as a target for build. You can download SDKs, which are available.